# Does flashing a recovery only affect the system?

Tags: recovery-mode, nexus-5, twrp

I am trying to get my stock recovery back so as, I could install my updates 5.0.1 on my nexus 5. I flashed my recovery from TWRP to stock recovery but my phone is now looping on boot animation screen.